# Google still crawling old site

Tags: php

I have recently re-designed my website and all the link structures and so on, i submitted a new site map for the new design and i am using a bit of code to keep track of when googlebot comes to my site and which pages it visits.

```
if ( strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Googlebot' ) !== false ) {
//Google bot is here
}
```

Every time it comes over though it visits pages from the old design  which now gives it a 404, anyway to make it stop crawling old site and to crawl new one instead?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 404 pages, use `HTTP 301` responses - they indicated a page has moved permanently and that all clients should update their links.

If you can link topic to topic (or better article to article) you're more likely to retain page rankings, but failing that link to the new domain and you'll get your ranks back pretty quickly.

Comment: It's still the same domain just diffrent pretty urls and design, i have over 10k dynamic pages so i am just wondering how i could redirect the old urls which don't exist anymore to there respective new url and would this tell google to crawl the new ones?

Comment: You'd either have to reinstate your old url mappings and force them to return the apporiate 301 headers or, more simple issue a blanket 301 for old page (maybe just recreate the root directory structure and issue a 301 inside those directories)? A blanket 301 shouldn't impact you too much as the domain will retain its score and the new urls will bubble up quickly

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **Google Webmaster Tools** I recently had a similar problem with a website redesign. The new content was in less than a day in Google search results. Just log in, add your site and use *`Site configuration > Sitemap link`* option to add your Sitemap URL.

This link help me a lot with the process: http://www.hmtweb.com/marketing-blog/how-to-use-fetch-as-googlebot-to-submit-a-recently-changed-page-to-googles-index-tutorial/

Good luck.